# json_encode runtime warning "Invalid UTF-8 sequence"

Tags: php, json

I retrieve a mysqli-resultset from the database, comes from a utf-8 encoded table and then is inserted into an array:

```
$json = array();

$query = "select artikel_titel from tblArtikel";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query))
{
    while($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    array_push($json, $line);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

The array is correctly built, [you can see it here](http://onezeromany.com/php/getArticles.php)
At the bottom of the page you can see the error created by the json_encode. How can I fix this?

```
Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in /customers/6/0/6/onezeromany.com/httpd.www/php/getArticles.php on line 13 Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in /customers/6/0/6/onezeromany.com/httpd.www/php/getArticles.php on line 13 Warning: json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in /customers/6/0/6/onezeromany.com/httpd.www/php/getArticles.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *do* have an invalid UTF-8 sequence in your data; apparently your database results are in ISO-8859-1. `json_encode` works **only** with UTF-8 data, according to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). You'll have to ensure that your data is in UTF-8 and your database connection uses UTF-8 as well; alternatively, you can use [`iconv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert your results to UTF-8 before feeding them to `json_encode`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how you found out they were not UTF-8?

Comment: Your dump showed an [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character) in several strings, which were displayed correctly after I forced my browser's encoding to ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and using [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) after the mysqli connect statement solved the problem.

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'test');
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Hope it helps!